# Identify the background image of a dragon from this book cover

Tags: dragons, object-identification

There's a [publishing house in Spain](http://eraseunavez.org/epages/ec2503.sf/es_ES/?ObjectPath=/Shops/ec2503/Categories) that is [rumoured to be unscrupulous in its methods](https://www.google.es/search?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aes-ES%3Aofficial&channel=sb&dcr=0&ei=o-KKWub_E42xkwWkppCADg&q=entrelineas%20editores%20timo&oq=entrelineas%20editores%20timo&gs_l=psy-ab.3...27202.28047.0.28593.5.5.0.0.0.0.138.621.0j5.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.4.516...0j0i22i30k1j33i160k1.0.2YOWw67wFLU). I have found by chance the cover of a book of theirs and I am almost certain that it is a copyright infringement of an illustration of some well-known illustrator, but I do not know who.

[image]

I'm almost sure it's copyright infringement, because at first glance you can see a technically good painting that contrasts with a series of additional details of very rough quality. If you buy the rights of a profesional fantastic illustrator you don't usually spoil his work with shoddy homemade additions.

Can you help me identify the picture with the dragon?

Comment: Is there any suggestion that this was plagiarised? Or is this merely your supposition?

Comment: It appears to be related to Dungeons and Dragons. At least that is what Google has told me.

Comment: [This also appears to be the full image](http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/13900000/Dragon-Wallpaper-dragons-13975557-1280-800.jpg)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That image reminds me of Gandalf vs Balrog in Moria (If you replace the dragon with the Balrog)

Comment: That font though..

Comment: *plagiarism* the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own. Is there anywhere someone claims this is their own work? Do you instead mean copyright infringement?

Comment: I hear your desire to expose and humiliate the publishing house, but you create legal liability for both yourself and the SE platform by doing it here.  It would help that issue a great deal, and not harm your question at all, to crop off the top title and bottom author and logo.  This would anonymize the usage, and deny them any fertile ground to claim you disparaged them particularly.

Comment: @Harper I never had any relation with that publishing house. I can prove it if necessary. I have a university background in law, although I am a civil servant and not a practicing lawyer and, of course, the laws in my country may be different from those in the US or Great Britain. According to the laws of my country, where I am writing this, a series of educated public quesses about business facts (not honor, not sex, not family, not murder) that are easy to prove (or deny) do not constitute libel.

Comment: @Harper  I admit that the laws in other countries, where I am not writing this, may be different, but my legal background allows me to believe that I am acting prudently and that, in finding out if a copyright infringement has been committed, my prudent behavior intends to protect a greater good such as the interests of that graphic artist. If the publishing house has acted in good faith, it will be easy and swift to show here and absolutely no harm will be made to them.

Comment: @Harper but, of course, if there is a big group of users that think like you i won't deny an edit, and, of course, i deny having any desire to humiliate anyone and you shouldn't attribute that desire to me.

Comment: @Ginasius obviously I touched a nerve, I am not meaning to offend your ego and I did not mean to get under your skin to the point where you wrote 3 replies.  .  The edit I propose does no harm, maybe you should ask yourself why it bothers you?

Comment: @Harper I didn't make three comments, I made one full of legal concepts that went too long and I had to divide. Legalese is like that in all countries. :-D Your comment (not your proposed edit) bothered me because I used to be an editor in wikipedia and there you must always presume good faith. Your comment started with just the opposite mood of presuming good faith. I'm not sure if that's also one of the principles of stackexchange, but it's easy to understand why I took your accusations of bad faith as offensive and overly personal. I won't presume bad faith in you but I'm deducing bad taste

Comment: I did presume good faith, and my writing was sympathetic and kind.  Look, I've been there too.  Sometimes it can be hard to see even the fairest criticism as anything but personal, bad-faith and nasty. The brain can get very busy rationalizing how you are perfect and they are *oh so wrong*.  It's best to try to keep that brain away from the keyboard :)  Rest assured the feeling does pass and you emerge better for the experience.  In a civilized society, dissent isn't damage.  I wish you the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73389/discussion-between-ginasius-and-harper).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The user "88grzes" on Deviant Art claims to be original artist of the image and as posted it [here](https://techgnotic.deviantart.com/art/Baptism-of-Fire-158967335) calling it "Baptism of Fire". Along with the image they also have the following description.

> Thanks for all comments in other works, I try to reply everyone but it take a lot of time ;/ (and all new interface stuff ;p)
>   Anyway finally I found some while to end this piece. I hope you like it! :)

This suggests it is their image and the one they include has a copyright watermark on it. However, I have seen the image without this watermark (though this could have been edited out) so it's not 100% conclusive.

This is the full size original image too.

[image: Baptism of Fire]

However, I have seen the image in lots of free wallpaper galleries and other sites also claim the image is free use so who knows.

As @Federico comments below this is also the first result for the image when you search for it on [TinEye](https://tineye.com/search/dffd6fa3cd606971400849dfdafea429038b9333/?sort=crawl_date&order=asc) suggesting it is the original.

Comment: Plagiarism has nothing to do with law, nor whether something is "free use" or not.

Comment: @OrangeDog I repeat I am not a lawyer, I have not studied law, I know next to nothing about law. I essentially posted what appears to be the correct source and then some additional comments about why it may or may not be plagiarism/copyright infringement. If you think I may have muddied the waters between the two things feel free to edit it to be more correct.

Comment: As 88grzes is the only person claiming to have created this image, they're the only person who could be committing plagiarism.

Comment: @OrangeDog I think you may be being intentionally difficult with regards to the law here. If they're the only one claiming to have created it chances are they created it...

Comment: It's got nothing to do with law. Plagiarism is not a legal issue. Your answer looks like it's actually about copyright infringement (in which case it doesn't answer the question). If it is actually about plagiarism then it is completely wrong.

Comment: @OrangeDog Like I said you appear to know more about the law/plagiarism than I do. As you feel strongly about this, and I don't know enough, it seems like it would be best for you to make an edit to clear things up.

Comment: Fine. I've removed all references to plagiarism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've sent a message to the (suposed) author, and waiting for more information about its copyright status, I'm glad to accept it.

Comment: @Ginasius No problem, feel free to update me if/when you get a response and I'll edit accordingly. Just a note though that although they appear to be the original artist it may not be the case but from what I found they was my best guess.

Comment: TinEye suggests that the DeviantArt image is the original, if we are to believe that the first one to be posted is the original. https://tineye.com/search/dffd6fa3cd606971400849dfdafea429038b9333/?sort=crawl_date&order=asc

Comment: That quote needs more emoticons.